# Function to Calculate a CRC16 Checksum

Tags: c, crc, crc16

I'm working on a library to provide simple reliable communication over an RS232 or RS485 connection.  Part of this code involves using a CRC16 checksum on the data to detect corruption from line noise.  I've created a function to calculate a CRC16 checksum, but it doesn't seem to be outputting correct values.

The relevant code I've written is below (it can also be found [here](https://gist.github.com/2666368)).

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define CRC16 0x8005

uint16_t gen_crc16(const uint8_t *data, uint16_t size)
{
    uint16_t out = 0;
    int bits_read = 0, bit_flag;

    /* Sanity check: */
    if(data == NULL)
        return 0;

    while(size > 0)
    {
        bit_flag = out >> 15;

        /* Get next bit: */
        out <<= 1;
        out |= (*data >> (7 - bits_read)) & 1;

        /* Increment bit counter: */
        bits_read++;
        if(bits_read > 7)
        {
            bits_read = 0;
            data++;
            size--;
        }

        /* Cycle check: */
        if(bit_flag)
            out ^= CRC16;
    }

    return out;
}
```

I'm checking my output against [this online CRC calculator](http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html).

I've come to the conclusion that either my understanding of how to calculate a CRC16 is wrong, or the online calculator is wrong (the former seems more likely).  Can someone tell me where I might be going wrong?

Comment: See also my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4455257/crc16-checksum-hcs08-vs-kermit-vs-xmodem?rq=1 which was based on the same online calculator, and includes a handy matrix table comparing the various formulas.

Comment: Don't use any of the bitwise code posted here. Use the table-driven algorithm. It is 8 times as fast.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

There are several details you need to 'match up' with for a particular CRC implementation - even using the same polynomial there can be different results because of minor differences in how data bits are handled, using a particular initial value for the CRC (sometimes it's zero, sometimes 0xffff), and/or inverting the bits of the CRC. For example, sometimes one implementation will work from the low order bits of the data bytes up, while sometimes they'll work from the high order bits down (as yours currently does).

Also, you need to 'push out' the last bits of the CRC after you've run all the data bits through.

Keep in mind that CRC algorithms were designed to be implemented in hardware, so some of how bit ordering is handled may not make so much sense from a software point of view.

If you want to match the CRC16 with polynomial 0x8005 as shown on the lammertbies.nl CRC calculator page, you need to make the following changes to your CRC function:

- a) run the data bits through the CRC loop starting from the least significant bit instead of from the most significant bit
- b) push the last 16 bits of the CRC out of the CRC register after you've finished with the input data
- c) reverse the CRC bits (I'm guessing this bit is a carry over from hardware implementations)

So, your function might look like:

```
#define CRC16 0x8005

uint16_t gen_crc16(const uint8_t *data, uint16_t size)
{
    uint16_t out = 0;
    int bits_read = 0, bit_flag;

    /* Sanity check: */
    if(data == NULL)
        return 0;

    while(size > 0)
    {
        bit_flag = out >> 15;

        /* Get next bit: */
        out <<= 1;
        out |= (*data >> bits_read) & 1; // item a) work from the least significant bits

        /* Increment bit counter: */
        bits_read++;
        if(bits_read > 7)
        {
            bits_read = 0;
            data++;
            size--;
        }

        /* Cycle check: */
        if(bit_flag)
            out ^= CRC16;

    }

    // item b) "push out" the last 16 bits
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        bit_flag = out >> 15;
        out <<= 1;
        if(bit_flag)
            out ^= CRC16;
    }

    // item c) reverse the bits
    uint16_t crc = 0;
    i = 0x8000;
    int j = 0x0001;
    for (; i != 0; i >>=1, j <<= 1) {
        if (i & out) crc |= j;
    }

    return crc;
}
```

That function returns `0xbb3d` for me when I pass in `"123456789"`.

Comment: I completely forgot about "pushing out" the last 16 bits.  I can't believe I didn't catch that.  As for the bit reversing... it probably would've taken me forever to figure that out.  Thanks.

Comment: This file will require a define in above this function #define CRC16 0x8005 based on the question code. https://gist.github.com/jlamothe/2666368

Comment: @Michael I have a question. It returns 0x2538 to me if I pass 0xa1b3. But it returns 0 if I pass 0xa1b3 0x3825 which I think it should be 0xa1b3 0x2538. Why it need to be exchange the endian here?

Comment: @scorpiozj: I couldn't really tell you. But it seems that if you want to append the CRC to a buffer (in order for a CRC check to result in 0), you have to append the 16 CRC value in little-endian order. Since the function operates on the data in the buffer on a byte-by-byte basis, this will be true whether the machine is big-endian or little-endian.

Comment: This implementation only works in 32 or 64 bit integer environments. If sizeof(int) == 2, this fails. Change the type of i from int to uint16_t.

Comment: That is a truly awful implementation. The exact same CRC can be computed far more elegantly and efficiently, even when done bit-wise. Thusly: `uint16_t crc16(uint8_t const *data, size_t size) {
    uint16_t crc = 0;
    while (size--) {
        crc ^= *data++;
        for (unsigned k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xa001 : crc >> 1;
    }
    return crc;
}`

Comment: @MarkAdler , sorry for ignorance, I know that your code is fine and it works, but that means 0xa001, I know it's not the polynomial (in this case 0x8005)

Comment: @PipeSoto The CRC is bit-reversed, so for an efficient implementation, the polynomial is bit-reversed (instead of the alternative, which would be to bit reverse all of the input and the result). `0xa001` is `0x8005` reversed.

Comment: Hi @MarkAdler, your code works perfectly for me however I can't see how the "accepted answer" and your code is equivalent. I've attached an excerpt for your reference [here](https://gist.github.com/ganindu7/30326a54cd1982221191a2d7d8d1bee8)

Comment: @Ganindu Your test needs to be `uint16_t crc_1 = gen_crc16(pattern1, 8);`, not `uint8_t crc_1 = gen_crc16(pattern1, 8);`. And you need to use exactly what I wrote for my code.

Comment: Thanks Mark for noticing my silly mistake!! the confusing bit was somehow I understood the Modcon's modbus protocol reference as I have to right shift and then extract the LSB(it) and XOR with 0XA001. which cascaded into a slight confusion. tbh I still don't understand how @MichaelBurr 's answer can be modified to make my version work. I don't think his implementation sucks because he's trying to correct Jonathon's question (which works for starting CRC 0x0000 case without issues.)

Answer (score 51):

Here follows a working code to calculate crc16 CCITT. I tested it and the results matched with those provided by http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html.

```
unsigned short crc16(const unsigned char* data_p, unsigned char length){
    unsigned char x;
    unsigned short crc = 0xFFFF;

    while (length--){
        x = crc >> 8 ^ *data_p++;
        x ^= x>>4;
        crc = (crc << 8) ^ ((unsigned short)(x << 12)) ^ ((unsigned short)(x <<5)) ^ ((unsigned short)x);
    }
    return crc;
}
```

Comment: CRC-16-CCITT (poly 0x1021) is the most common CRC-16 and most well-proven in use, so I'd recommend to use this one. For example, this is the CRC you'll find inside microcontrollers with built-in CRC calculators.

Comment: Two things: You might find some CRC-CCITT implementations expecting an initial crc value of `0x1D0F` to match test vectors. Secondly, `unsigned short` only guarantees *at least* 16 bits, which is normative, but *could* be wider. So I'd suggest a final `crc &= 0xffff;` And with that, you don't need the `(unsigned short)` casts in the last line of the loop, and wider types should work fine.

Comment: This routine doesn't work... It _does_ give the correct answer for short strings such as "123456789" but doesn't give correct answers for longer strings (in my case a 260 byte binary).

Comment: @Richard: 260 is too big to fit in the `unsigned char length` parameter. Changing the type of that parameter to `unsigned short` should fix it: `unsigned short crc16(const unsigned char* data_p, unsigned short length)`.

Comment: To use the above function use **strlen** and not **sizeof** function encapsulation for the 2nd paramter `char test[6]="XYZ,0"; unsigned short crc16_ccitt = crc16(test,strlen(test));`

Comment: This algorithm is close to CCITT but wrong. Please see the test strings at http://srecord.sourceforge.net/crc16-ccitt.html

Comment: Just so there is no confusion, this is highly optimized crc16 with the following configuration: `poly=0x1021, init=0xFFFF, xorout=0x0000 = CRC-16/CCITT-FALSE, CRC-16/IBM-3740`. You can use `init=0x0000` for `CRC-16/XMODEM`. For the *real* CRC-16/CCITT, the code will be more complicated due to needing **reflection** of both input and output bits. It is still very good, fastest tableless CRC-16 you can find.

Comment: `x` should be casted before shifting it to the left. Here it is casted after `((unsigned short)(x << 12))`. The actual code might cause errors regarding compiler standard. It's also preferable to use `uint16_t` than `unsigned short`. So good line will be 
`crc = (crc << 8) ^ ( ((uint16_t)x) << 12 ) ^ ( ((uint16_t)x) <<5 ) ^ ((uint16_t)x);`   (not tested)

Comment: Easier way might be to just declare `x` as `uint16_t` and forget type casting.

Answer (score 8):

[crcany](https://github.com/madler/crcany) will generate efficient C code for any CRC, and includes a library of over one hundred known CRC definitions.

Efficient CRC code uses tables instead of bit-wise calculations. crcany generates both byte-wise routines and word-wise routines, the latter tuned to the architecture they are generated on. Word-wise is the fastest. Byte-wise is still much faster than bit-wise, but the implementation is more easily portable over architectures.

You do not seem to have a protocol definition with a specific CRC definition that you need to match. In this case, you can pick any 16-bit CRC in the [catalog](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/16.htm), and you will get good performance.

If you have a relatively low bit error rate, e.g. single digit number of errors per packet, and you want to maximize your error detection performance, you would need to look at the packet size you are applying the CRC to, assuming that that is constant or bounded, and look at the performance of the best polynomials in [Philip Koopman's extensive research](http://users.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/crc/index.html). The classic CRCs, such as the CCITT/Kermit 16-bit CRC or the X.25 16-bit CRC are not the best performers.

One of the good 16-bit performers in Koopman's tables that is also in the catalog of CRCs used in practice is CRC-16/DNP. It has very good performance detecting up to 6-bit errors in a packet. Following is the code generated by crcany for that CRC definition. This code assumes a little-endian architecture for the word-wise calculation, e.g. Intel x86 and x86-64, and it assumes that `uintmax_t` is 64 bits. crcany can be used to generate alternative code for big-endian and other word sizes.

*crc16dnp.h:*

```
// The _bit, _byte, and _word routines return the CRC of the len bytes at mem,
// applied to the previous CRC value, crc. If mem is NULL, then the other
// arguments are ignored, and the initial CRC, i.e. the CRC of zero bytes, is
// returned. Those routines will all return the same result, differing only in
// speed and code complexity. The _rem routine returns the CRC of the remaining
// bits in the last byte, for when the number of bits in the message is not a
// multiple of eight. The low bits bits of the low byte of val are applied to
// crc. bits must be in 0..8.

#include <stddef.h>

// Compute the CRC a bit at a time.
unsigned crc16dnp_bit(unsigned crc, void const *mem, size_t len);

// Compute the CRC of the low bits bits in val.
unsigned crc16dnp_rem(unsigned crc, unsigned val, unsigned bits);

// Compute the CRC a byte at a time.
unsigned crc16dnp_byte(unsigned crc, void const *mem, size_t len);

// Compute the CRC a word at a time.
unsigned crc16dnp_word(unsigned crc, void const *mem, size_t len);
```

*crc16dnp.c:*

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "crc16dnp.h"

// This code assumes that unsigned is 4 bytes.

unsigned crc16dnp_bit(unsigned crc, void const *mem, size_t len) {
    unsigned char const *data = mem;
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0xffff;
    crc = ~crc;
    crc &= 0xffff;
    while (len--) {
        crc ^= *data++;
        for (unsigned k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xa6bc : crc >> 1;
    }
    crc ^= 0xffff;
    return crc;
}

unsigned crc16dnp_rem(unsigned crc, unsigned val, unsigned bits) {
    crc = ~crc;
    crc &= 0xffff;
    val &= (1U << bits) - 1;
    crc ^= val;
    while (bits--)
        crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0xa6bc : crc >> 1;
    crc ^= 0xffff;
    return crc;
}

#define table_byte table_word[0]

static unsigned short const table_word[][256] = {
   {0xed35, 0xdb6b, 0x8189, 0xb7d7, 0x344d, 0x0213, 0x58f1, 0x6eaf, 0x12bc, 0x24e2,
    0x7e00, 0x485e, 0xcbc4, 0xfd9a, 0xa778, 0x9126, 0x5f5e, 0x6900, 0x33e2, 0x05bc,
    0x8626, 0xb078, 0xea9a, 0xdcc4, 0xa0d7, 0x9689, 0xcc6b, 0xfa35, 0x79af, 0x4ff1,
    0x1513, 0x234d, 0xc49a, 0xf2c4, 0xa826, 0x9e78, 0x1de2, 0x2bbc, 0x715e, 0x4700,
    0x3b13, 0x0d4d, 0x57af, 0x61f1, 0xe26b, 0xd435, 0x8ed7, 0xb889, 0x76f1, 0x40af,
    0x1a4d, 0x2c13, 0xaf89, 0x99d7, 0xc335, 0xf56b, 0x8978, 0xbf26, 0xe5c4, 0xd39a,
    0x5000, 0x665e, 0x3cbc, 0x0ae2, 0xbe6b, 0x8835, 0xd2d7, 0xe489, 0x6713, 0x514d,
    0x0baf, 0x3df1, 0x41e2, 0x77bc, 0x2d5e, 0x1b00, 0x989a, 0xaec4, 0xf426, 0xc278,
    0x0c00, 0x3a5e, 0x60bc, 0x56e2, 0xd578, 0xe326, 0xb9c4, 0x8f9a, 0xf389, 0xc5d7,
    0x9f35, 0xa96b, 0x2af1, 0x1caf, 0x464d, 0x7013, 0x97c4, 0xa19a, 0xfb78, 0xcd26,
    0x4ebc, 0x78e2, 0x2200, 0x145e, 0x684d, 0x5e13, 0x04f1, 0x32af, 0xb135, 0x876b,
    0xdd89, 0xebd7, 0x25af, 0x13f1, 0x4913, 0x7f4d, 0xfcd7, 0xca89, 0x906b, 0xa635,
    0xda26, 0xec78, 0xb69a, 0x80c4, 0x035e, 0x3500, 0x6fe2, 0x59bc, 0x4b89, 0x7dd7,
    0x2735, 0x116b, 0x92f1, 0xa4af, 0xfe4d, 0xc813, 0xb400, 0x825e, 0xd8bc, 0xeee2,
    0x6d78, 0x5b26, 0x01c4, 0x379a, 0xf9e2, 0xcfbc, 0x955e, 0xa300, 0x209a, 0x16c4,
    0x4c26, 0x7a78, 0x066b, 0x3035, 0x6ad7, 0x5c89, 0xdf13, 0xe94d, 0xb3af, 0x85f1,
    0x6226, 0x5478, 0x0e9a, 0x38c4, 0xbb5e, 0x8d00, 0xd7e2, 0xe1bc, 0x9daf, 0xabf1,
    0xf113, 0xc74d, 0x44d7, 0x7289, 0x286b, 0x1e35, 0xd04d, 0xe613, 0xbcf1, 0x8aaf,
    0x0935, 0x3f6b, 0x6589, 0x53d7, 0x2fc4, 0x199a, 0x4378, 0x7526, 0xf6bc, 0xc0e2,
    0x9a00, 0xac5e, 0x18d7, 0x2e89, 0x746b, 0x4235, 0xc1af, 0xf7f1, 0xad13, 0x9b4d,
    0xe75e, 0xd100, 0x8be2, 0xbdbc, 0x3e26, 0x0878, 0x529a, 0x64c4, 0xaabc, 0x9ce2,
    0xc600, 0xf05e, 0x73c4, 0x459a, 0x1f78, 0x2926, 0x5535, 0x636b, 0x3989, 0x0fd7,
    0x8c4d, 0xba13, 0xe0f1, 0xd6af, 0x3178, 0x0726, 0x5dc4, 0x6b9a, 0xe800, 0xde5e,
    0x84bc, 0xb2e2, 0xcef1, 0xf8af, 0xa24d, 0x9413, 0x1789, 0x21d7, 0x7b35, 0x4d6b,
    0x8313, 0xb54d, 0xefaf, 0xd9f1, 0x5a6b, 0x6c35, 0x36d7, 0x0089, 0x7c9a, 0x4ac4,
    0x1026, 0x2678, 0xa5e2, 0x93bc, 0xc95e, 0xff00},
   {0x740f, 0xdf41, 0x6fea, 0xc4a4, 0x43c5, 0xe88b, 0x5820, 0xf36e, 0x1b9b, 0xb0d5,
    0x007e, 0xab30, 0x2c51, 0x871f, 0x37b4, 0x9cfa, 0xab27, 0x0069, 0xb0c2, 0x1b8c,
    0x9ced, 0x37a3, 0x8708, 0x2c46, 0xc4b3, 0x6ffd, 0xdf56, 0x7418, 0xf379, 0x5837,
    0xe89c, 0x43d2, 0x8726, 0x2c68, 0x9cc3, 0x378d, 0xb0ec, 0x1ba2, 0xab09, 0x0047,
    0xe8b2, 0x43fc, 0xf357, 0x5819, 0xdf78, 0x7436, 0xc49d, 0x6fd3, 0x580e, 0xf340,
    0x43eb, 0xe8a5, 0x6fc4, 0xc48a, 0x7421, 0xdf6f, 0x379a, 0x9cd4, 0x2c7f, 0x8731,
    0x0050, 0xab1e, 0x1bb5, 0xb0fb, 0xdf24, 0x746a, 0xc4c1, 0x6f8f, 0xe8ee, 0x43a0,
    0xf30b, 0x5845, 0xb0b0, 0x1bfe, 0xab55, 0x001b, 0x877a, 0x2c34, 0x9c9f, 0x37d1,
    0x000c, 0xab42, 0x1be9, 0xb0a7, 0x37c6, 0x9c88, 0x2c23, 0x876d, 0x6f98, 0xc4d6,
    0x747d, 0xdf33, 0x5852, 0xf31c, 0x43b7, 0xe8f9, 0x2c0d, 0x8743, 0x37e8, 0x9ca6,
    0x1bc7, 0xb089, 0x0022, 0xab6c, 0x4399, 0xe8d7, 0x587c, 0xf332, 0x7453, 0xdf1d,
    0x6fb6, 0xc4f8, 0xf325, 0x586b, 0xe8c0, 0x438e, 0xc4ef, 0x6fa1, 0xdf0a, 0x7444,
    0x9cb1, 0x37ff, 0x8754, 0x2c1a, 0xab7b, 0x0035, 0xb09e, 0x1bd0, 0x6f20, 0xc46e,
    0x74c5, 0xdf8b, 0x58ea, 0xf3a4, 0x430f, 0xe841, 0x00b4, 0xabfa, 0x1b51, 0xb01f,
    0x377e, 0x9c30, 0x2c9b, 0x87d5, 0xb008, 0x1b46, 0xabed, 0x00a3, 0x87c2, 0x2c8c,
    0x9c27, 0x3769, 0xdf9c, 0x74d2, 0xc479, 0x6f37, 0xe856, 0x4318, 0xf3b3, 0x58fd,
    0x9c09, 0x3747, 0x87ec, 0x2ca2, 0xabc3, 0x008d, 0xb026, 0x1b68, 0xf39d, 0x58d3,
    0xe878, 0x4336, 0xc457, 0x6f19, 0xdfb2, 0x74fc, 0x4321, 0xe86f, 0x58c4, 0xf38a,
    0x74eb, 0xdfa5, 0x6f0e, 0xc440, 0x2cb5, 0x87fb, 0x3750, 0x9c1e, 0x1b7f, 0xb031,
    0x009a, 0xabd4, 0xc40b, 0x6f45, 0xdfee, 0x74a0, 0xf3c1, 0x588f, 0xe824, 0x436a,
    0xab9f, 0x00d1, 0xb07a, 0x1b34, 0x9c55, 0x371b, 0x87b0, 0x2cfe, 0x1b23, 0xb06d,
    0x00c6, 0xab88, 0x2ce9, 0x87a7, 0x370c, 0x9c42, 0x74b7, 0xdff9, 0x6f52, 0xc41c,
    0x437d, 0xe833, 0x5898, 0xf3d6, 0x3722, 0x9c6c, 0x2cc7, 0x8789, 0x00e8, 0xaba6,
    0x1b0d, 0xb043, 0x58b6, 0xf3f8, 0x4353, 0xe81d, 0x6f7c, 0xc432, 0x7499, 0xdfd7,
    0xe80a, 0x4344, 0xf3ef, 0x58a1, 0xdfc0, 0x748e, 0xc425, 0x6f6b, 0x879e, 0x2cd0,
    0x9c7b, 0x3735, 0xb054, 0x1b1a, 0xabb1, 0x00ff},
   {0x7c67, 0x65df, 0x4f17, 0x56af, 0x1a87, 0x033f, 0x29f7, 0x304f, 0xb1a7, 0xa81f,
    0x82d7, 0x9b6f, 0xd747, 0xceff, 0xe437, 0xfd8f, 0xaa9e, 0xb326, 0x99ee, 0x8056,
    0xcc7e, 0xd5c6, 0xff0e, 0xe6b6, 0x675e, 0x7ee6, 0x542e, 0x4d96, 0x01be, 0x1806,
    0x32ce, 0x2b76, 0x9cec, 0x8554, 0xaf9c, 0xb624, 0xfa0c, 0xe3b4, 0xc97c, 0xd0c4,
    0x512c, 0x4894, 0x625c, 0x7be4, 0x37cc, 0x2e74, 0x04bc, 0x1d04, 0x4a15, 0x53ad,
    0x7965, 0x60dd, 0x2cf5, 0x354d, 0x1f85, 0x063d, 0x87d5, 0x9e6d, 0xb4a5, 0xad1d,
    0xe135, 0xf88d, 0xd245, 0xcbfd, 0xf008, 0xe9b0, 0xc378, 0xdac0, 0x96e8, 0x8f50,
    0xa598, 0xbc20, 0x3dc8, 0x2470, 0x0eb8, 0x1700, 0x5b28, 0x4290, 0x6858, 0x71e0,
    0x26f1, 0x3f49, 0x1581, 0x0c39, 0x4011, 0x59a9, 0x7361, 0x6ad9, 0xeb31, 0xf289,
    0xd841, 0xc1f9, 0x8dd1, 0x9469, 0xbea1, 0xa719, 0x1083, 0x093b, 0x23f3, 0x3a4b,
    0x7663, 0x6fdb, 0x4513, 0x5cab, 0xdd43, 0xc4fb, 0xee33, 0xf78b, 0xbba3, 0xa21b,
    0x88d3, 0x916b, 0xc67a, 0xdfc2, 0xf50a, 0xecb2, 0xa09a, 0xb922, 0x93ea, 0x8a52,
    0x0bba, 0x1202, 0x38ca, 0x2172, 0x6d5a, 0x74e2, 0x5e2a, 0x4792, 0x29c0, 0x3078,
    0x1ab0, 0x0308, 0x4f20, 0x5698, 0x7c50, 0x65e8, 0xe400, 0xfdb8, 0xd770, 0xcec8,
    0x82e0, 0x9b58, 0xb190, 0xa828, 0xff39, 0xe681, 0xcc49, 0xd5f1, 0x99d9, 0x8061,
    0xaaa9, 0xb311, 0x32f9, 0x2b41, 0x0189, 0x1831, 0x5419, 0x4da1, 0x6769, 0x7ed1,
    0xc94b, 0xd0f3, 0xfa3b, 0xe383, 0xafab, 0xb613, 0x9cdb, 0x8563, 0x048b, 0x1d33,
    0x37fb, 0x2e43, 0x626b, 0x7bd3, 0x511b, 0x48a3, 0x1fb2, 0x060a, 0x2cc2, 0x357a,
    0x7952, 0x60ea, 0x4a22, 0x539a, 0xd272, 0xcbca, 0xe102, 0xf8ba, 0xb492, 0xad2a,
    0x87e2, 0x9e5a, 0xa5af, 0xbc17, 0x96df, 0x8f67, 0xc34f, 0xdaf7, 0xf03f, 0xe987,
    0x686f, 0x71d7, 0x5b1f, 0x42a7, 0x0e8f, 0x1737, 0x3dff, 0x2447, 0x7356, 0x6aee,
    0x4026, 0x599e, 0x15b6, 0x0c0e, 0x26c6, 0x3f7e, 0xbe96, 0xa72e, 0x8de6, 0x945e,
    0xd876, 0xc1ce, 0xeb06, 0xf2be, 0x4524, 0x5c9c, 0x7654, 0x6fec, 0x23c4, 0x3a7c,
    0x10b4, 0x090c, 0x88e4, 0x915c, 0xbb94, 0xa22c, 0xee04, 0xf7bc, 0xdd74, 0xc4cc,
    0x93dd, 0x8a65, 0xa0ad, 0xb915, 0xf53d, 0xec85, 0xc64d, 0xdff5, 0x5e1d, 0x47a5,
    0x6d6d, 0x74d5, 0x38fd, 0x2145, 0x0b8d, 0x1235},
   {0xf917, 0x3bff, 0x31be, 0xf356, 0x253c, 0xe7d4, 0xed95, 0x2f7d, 0x0c38, 0xced0,
    0xc491, 0x0679, 0xd013, 0x12fb, 0x18ba, 0xda52, 0x5e30, 0x9cd8, 0x9699, 0x5471,
    0x821b, 0x40f3, 0x4ab2, 0x885a, 0xab1f, 0x69f7, 0x63b6, 0xa15e, 0x7734, 0xb5dc,
    0xbf9d, 0x7d75, 0xfa20, 0x38c8, 0x3289, 0xf061, 0x260b, 0xe4e3, 0xeea2, 0x2c4a,
    0x0f0f, 0xcde7, 0xc7a6, 0x054e, 0xd324, 0x11cc, 0x1b8d, 0xd965, 0x5d07, 0x9fef,
    0x95ae, 0x5746, 0x812c, 0x43c4, 0x4985, 0x8b6d, 0xa828, 0x6ac0, 0x6081, 0xa269,
    0x7403, 0xb6eb, 0xbcaa, 0x7e42, 0xff79, 0x3d91, 0x37d0, 0xf538, 0x2352, 0xe1ba,
    0xebfb, 0x2913, 0x0a56, 0xc8be, 0xc2ff, 0x0017, 0xd67d, 0x1495, 0x1ed4, 0xdc3c,
    0x585e, 0x9ab6, 0x90f7, 0x521f, 0x8475, 0x469d, 0x4cdc, 0x8e34, 0xad71, 0x6f99,
    0x65d8, 0xa730, 0x715a, 0xb3b2, 0xb9f3, 0x7b1b, 0xfc4e, 0x3ea6, 0x34e7, 0xf60f,
    0x2065, 0xe28d, 0xe8cc, 0x2a24, 0x0961, 0xcb89, 0xc1c8, 0x0320, 0xd54a, 0x17a2,
    0x1de3, 0xdf0b, 0x5b69, 0x9981, 0x93c0, 0x5128, 0x8742, 0x45aa, 0x4feb, 0x8d03,
    0xae46, 0x6cae, 0x66ef, 0xa407, 0x726d, 0xb085, 0xbac4, 0x782c, 0xf5cb, 0x3723,
    0x3d62, 0xff8a, 0x29e0, 0xeb08, 0xe149, 0x23a1, 0x00e4, 0xc20c, 0xc84d, 0x0aa5,
    0xdccf, 0x1e27, 0x1466, 0xd68e, 0x52ec, 0x9004, 0x9a45, 0x58ad, 0x8ec7, 0x4c2f,
    0x466e, 0x8486, 0xa7c3, 0x652b, 0x6f6a, 0xad82, 0x7be8, 0xb900, 0xb341, 0x71a9,
    0xf6fc, 0x3414, 0x3e55, 0xfcbd, 0x2ad7, 0xe83f, 0xe27e, 0x2096, 0x03d3, 0xc13b,
    0xcb7a, 0x0992, 0xdff8, 0x1d10, 0x1751, 0xd5b9, 0x51db, 0x9333, 0x9972, 0x5b9a,
    0x8df0, 0x4f18, 0x4559, 0x87b1, 0xa4f4, 0x661c, 0x6c5d, 0xaeb5, 0x78df, 0xba37,
    0xb076, 0x729e, 0xf3a5, 0x314d, 0x3b0c, 0xf9e4, 0x2f8e, 0xed66, 0xe727, 0x25cf,
    0x068a, 0xc462, 0xce23, 0x0ccb, 0xdaa1, 0x1849, 0x1208, 0xd0e0, 0x5482, 0x966a,
    0x9c2b, 0x5ec3, 0x88a9, 0x4a41, 0x4000, 0x82e8, 0xa1ad, 0x6345, 0x6904, 0xabec,
    0x7d86, 0xbf6e, 0xb52f, 0x77c7, 0xf092, 0x327a, 0x383b, 0xfad3, 0x2cb9, 0xee51,
    0xe410, 0x26f8, 0x05bd, 0xc755, 0xcd14, 0x0ffc, 0xd996, 0x1b7e, 0x113f, 0xd3d7,
    0x57b5, 0x955d, 0x9f1c, 0x5df4, 0x8b9e, 0x4976, 0x4337, 0x81df, 0xa29a, 0x6072,
    0x6a33, 0xa8db, 0x7eb1, 0xbc59, 0xb618, 0x74f0},
   {0x3108, 0x120e, 0x7704, 0x5402, 0xbd10, 0x9e16, 0xfb1c, 0xd81a, 0x6441, 0x4747,
    0x224d, 0x014b, 0xe859, 0xcb5f, 0xae55, 0x8d53, 0x9b9a, 0xb89c, 0xdd96, 0xfe90,
    0x1782, 0x3484, 0x518e, 0x7288, 0xced3, 0xedd5, 0x88df, 0xabd9, 0x42cb, 0x61cd,
    0x04c7, 0x27c1, 0x2955, 0x0a53, 0x6f59, 0x4c5f, 0xa54d, 0x864b, 0xe341, 0xc047,
    0x7c1c, 0x5f1a, 0x3a10, 0x1916, 0xf004, 0xd302, 0xb608, 0x950e, 0x83c7, 0xa0c1,
    0xc5cb, 0xe6cd, 0x0fdf, 0x2cd9, 0x49d3, 0x6ad5, 0xd68e, 0xf588, 0x9082, 0xb384,
    0x5a96, 0x7990, 0x1c9a, 0x3f9c, 0x01b2, 0x22b4, 0x47be, 0x64b8, 0x8daa, 0xaeac,
    0xcba6, 0xe8a0, 0x54fb, 0x77fd, 0x12f7, 0x31f1, 0xd8e3, 0xfbe5, 0x9eef, 0xbde9,
    0xab20, 0x8826, 0xed2c, 0xce2a, 0x2738, 0x043e, 0x6134, 0x4232, 0xfe69, 0xdd6f,
    0xb865, 0x9b63, 0x7271, 0x5177, 0x347d, 0x177b, 0x19ef, 0x3ae9, 0x5fe3, 0x7ce5,
    0x95f7, 0xb6f1, 0xd3fb, 0xf0fd, 0x4ca6, 0x6fa0, 0x0aaa, 0x29ac, 0xc0be, 0xe3b8,
    0x86b2, 0xa5b4, 0xb37d, 0x907b, 0xf571, 0xd677, 0x3f65, 0x1c63, 0x7969, 0x5a6f,
    0xe634, 0xc532, 0xa038, 0x833e, 0x6a2c, 0x492a, 0x2c20, 0x0f26, 0x507c, 0x737a,
    0x1670, 0x3576, 0xdc64, 0xff62, 0x9a68, 0xb96e, 0x0535, 0x2633, 0x4339, 0x603f,
    0x892d, 0xaa2b, 0xcf21, 0xec27, 0xfaee, 0xd9e8, 0xbce2, 0x9fe4, 0x76f6, 0x55f0,
    0x30fa, 0x13fc, 0xafa7, 0x8ca1, 0xe9ab, 0xcaad, 0x23bf, 0x00b9, 0x65b3, 0x46b5,
    0x4821, 0x6b27, 0x0e2d, 0x2d2b, 0xc439, 0xe73f, 0x8235, 0xa133, 0x1d68, 0x3e6e,
    0x5b64, 0x7862, 0x9170, 0xb276, 0xd77c, 0xf47a, 0xe2b3, 0xc1b5, 0xa4bf, 0x87b9,
    0x6eab, 0x4dad, 0x28a7, 0x0ba1, 0xb7fa, 0x94fc, 0xf1f6, 0xd2f0, 0x3be2, 0x18e4,
    0x7dee, 0x5ee8, 0x60c6, 0x43c0, 0x26ca, 0x05cc, 0xecde, 0xcfd8, 0xaad2, 0x89d4,
    0x358f, 0x1689, 0x7383, 0x5085, 0xb997, 0x9a91, 0xff9b, 0xdc9d, 0xca54, 0xe952,
    0x8c58, 0xaf5e, 0x464c, 0x654a, 0x0040, 0x2346, 0x9f1d, 0xbc1b, 0xd911, 0xfa17,
    0x1305, 0x3003, 0x5509, 0x760f, 0x789b, 0x5b9d, 0x3e97, 0x1d91, 0xf483, 0xd785,
    0xb28f, 0x9189, 0x2dd2, 0x0ed4, 0x6bde, 0x48d8, 0xa1ca, 0x82cc, 0xe7c6, 0xc4c0,
    0xd209, 0xf10f, 0x9405, 0xb703, 0x5e11, 0x7d17, 0x181d, 0x3b1b, 0x8740, 0xa446,
    0xc14c, 0xe24a, 0x0b58, 0x285e, 0x4d54, 0x6e52},
   {0xffb8, 0x4a5f, 0xd90f, 0x6ce8, 0xb2d6, 0x0731, 0x9461, 0x2186, 0x6564, 0xd083,
    0x43d3, 0xf634, 0x280a, 0x9ded, 0x0ebd, 0xbb5a, 0x8779, 0x329e, 0xa1ce, 0x1429,
    0xca17, 0x7ff0, 0xeca0, 0x5947, 0x1da5, 0xa842, 0x3b12, 0x8ef5, 0x50cb, 0xe52c,
    0x767c, 0xc39b, 0x0e3a, 0xbbdd, 0x288d, 0x9d6a, 0x4354, 0xf6b3, 0x65e3, 0xd004,
    0x94e6, 0x2101, 0xb251, 0x07b6, 0xd988, 0x6c6f, 0xff3f, 0x4ad8, 0x76fb, 0xc31c,
    0x504c, 0xe5ab, 0x3b95, 0x8e72, 0x1d22, 0xa8c5, 0xec27, 0x59c0, 0xca90, 0x7f77,
    0xa149, 0x14ae, 0x87fe, 0x3219, 0x51c5, 0xe422, 0x7772, 0xc295, 0x1cab, 0xa94c,
    0x3a1c, 0x8ffb, 0xcb19, 0x7efe, 0xedae, 0x5849, 0x8677, 0x3390, 0xa0c0, 0x1527,
    0x2904, 0x9ce3, 0x0fb3, 0xba54, 0x646a, 0xd18d, 0x42dd, 0xf73a, 0xb3d8, 0x063f,
    0x956f, 0x2088, 0xfeb6, 0x4b51, 0xd801, 0x6de6, 0xa047, 0x15a0, 0x86f0, 0x3317,
    0xed29, 0x58ce, 0xcb9e, 0x7e79, 0x3a9b, 0x8f7c, 0x1c2c, 0xa9cb, 0x77f5, 0xc212,
    0x5142, 0xe4a5, 0xd886, 0x6d61, 0xfe31, 0x4bd6, 0x95e8, 0x200f, 0xb35f, 0x06b8,
    0x425a, 0xf7bd, 0x64ed, 0xd10a, 0x0f34, 0xbad3, 0x2983, 0x9c64, 0xee3b, 0x5bdc,
    0xc88c, 0x7d6b, 0xa355, 0x16b2, 0x85e2, 0x3005, 0x74e7, 0xc100, 0x5250, 0xe7b7,
    0x3989, 0x8c6e, 0x1f3e, 0xaad9, 0x96fa, 0x231d, 0xb04d, 0x05aa, 0xdb94, 0x6e73,
    0xfd23, 0x48c4, 0x0c26, 0xb9c1, 0x2a91, 0x9f76, 0x4148, 0xf4af, 0x67ff, 0xd218,
    0x1fb9, 0xaa5e, 0x390e, 0x8ce9, 0x52d7, 0xe730, 0x7460, 0xc187, 0x8565, 0x3082,
    0xa3d2, 0x1635, 0xc80b, 0x7dec, 0xeebc, 0x5b5b, 0x6778, 0xd29f, 0x41cf, 0xf428,
    0x2a16, 0x9ff1, 0x0ca1, 0xb946, 0xfda4, 0x4843, 0xdb13, 0x6ef4, 0xb0ca, 0x052d,
    0x967d, 0x239a, 0x4046, 0xf5a1, 0x66f1, 0xd316, 0x0d28, 0xb8cf, 0x2b9f, 0x9e78,
    0xda9a, 0x6f7d, 0xfc2d, 0x49ca, 0x97f4, 0x2213, 0xb143, 0x04a4, 0x3887, 0x8d60,
    0x1e30, 0xabd7, 0x75e9, 0xc00e, 0x535e, 0xe6b9, 0xa25b, 0x17bc, 0x84ec, 0x310b,
    0xef35, 0x5ad2, 0xc982, 0x7c65, 0xb1c4, 0x0423, 0x9773, 0x2294, 0xfcaa, 0x494d,
    0xda1d, 0x6ffa, 0x2b18, 0x9eff, 0x0daf, 0xb848, 0x6676, 0xd391, 0x40c1, 0xf526,
    0xc905, 0x7ce2, 0xefb2, 0x5a55, 0x846b, 0x318c, 0xa2dc, 0x173b, 0x53d9, 0xe63e,
    0x756e, 0xc089, 0x1eb7, 0xab50, 0x3800, 0x8de7},
   {0xc20e, 0x9d6c, 0x7cca, 0x23a8, 0xf2ff, 0xad9d, 0x4c3b, 0x1359, 0xa3ec, 0xfc8e,
    0x1d28, 0x424a, 0x931d, 0xcc7f, 0x2dd9, 0x72bb, 0x01ca, 0x5ea8, 0xbf0e, 0xe06c,
    0x313b, 0x6e59, 0x8fff, 0xd09d, 0x6028, 0x3f4a, 0xdeec, 0x818e, 0x50d9, 0x0fbb,
    0xee1d, 0xb17f, 0x08ff, 0x579d, 0xb63b, 0xe959, 0x380e, 0x676c, 0x86ca, 0xd9a8,
    0x691d, 0x367f, 0xd7d9, 0x88bb, 0x59ec, 0x068e, 0xe728, 0xb84a, 0xcb3b, 0x9459,
    0x75ff, 0x2a9d, 0xfbca, 0xa4a8, 0x450e, 0x1a6c, 0xaad9, 0xf5bb, 0x141d, 0x4b7f,
    0x9a28, 0xc54a, 0x24ec, 0x7b8e, 0x1a95, 0x45f7, 0xa451, 0xfb33, 0x2a64, 0x7506,
    0x94a0, 0xcbc2, 0x7b77, 0x2415, 0xc5b3, 0x9ad1, 0x4b86, 0x14e4, 0xf542, 0xaa20,
    0xd951, 0x8633, 0x6795, 0x38f7, 0xe9a0, 0xb6c2, 0x5764, 0x0806, 0xb8b3, 0xe7d1,
    0x0677, 0x5915, 0x8842, 0xd720, 0x3686, 0x69e4, 0xd064, 0x8f06, 0x6ea0, 0x31c2,
    0xe095, 0xbff7, 0x5e51, 0x0133, 0xb186, 0xeee4, 0x0f42, 0x5020, 0x8177, 0xde15,
    0x3fb3, 0x60d1, 0x13a0, 0x4cc2, 0xad64, 0xf206, 0x2351, 0x7c33, 0x9d95, 0xc2f7,
    0x7242, 0x2d20, 0xcc86, 0x93e4, 0x42b3, 0x1dd1, 0xfc77, 0xa315, 0x3e41, 0x6123,
    0x8085, 0xdfe7, 0x0eb0, 0x51d2, 0xb074, 0xef16, 0x5fa3, 0x00c1, 0xe167, 0xbe05,
    0x6f52, 0x3030, 0xd196, 0x8ef4, 0xfd85, 0xa2e7, 0x4341, 0x1c23, 0xcd74, 0x9216,
    0x73b0, 0x2cd2, 0x9c67, 0xc305, 0x22a3, 0x7dc1, 0xac96, 0xf3f4, 0x1252, 0x4d30,
    0xf4b0, 0xabd2, 0x4a74, 0x1516, 0xc441, 0x9b23, 0x7a85, 0x25e7, 0x9552, 0xca30,
    0x2b96, 0x74f4, 0xa5a3, 0xfac1, 0x1b67, 0x4405, 0x3774, 0x6816, 0x89b0, 0xd6d2,
    0x0785, 0x58e7, 0xb941, 0xe623, 0x5696, 0x09f4, 0xe852, 0xb730, 0x6667, 0x3905,
    0xd8a3, 0x87c1, 0xe6da, 0xb9b8, 0x581e, 0x077c, 0xd62b, 0x8949, 0x68ef, 0x378d,
    0x8738, 0xd85a, 0x39fc, 0x669e, 0xb7c9, 0xe8ab, 0x090d, 0x566f, 0x251e, 0x7a7c,
    0x9bda, 0xc4b8, 0x15ef, 0x4a8d, 0xab2b, 0xf449, 0x44fc, 0x1b9e, 0xfa38, 0xa55a,
    0x740d, 0x2b6f, 0xcac9, 0x95ab, 0x2c2b, 0x7349, 0x92ef, 0xcd8d, 0x1cda, 0x43b8,
    0xa21e, 0xfd7c, 0x4dc9, 0x12ab, 0xf30d, 0xac6f, 0x7d38, 0x225a, 0xc3fc, 0x9c9e,
    0xefef, 0xb08d, 0x512b, 0x0e49, 0xdf1e, 0x807c, 0x61da, 0x3eb8, 0x8e0d, 0xd16f,
    0x30c9, 0x6fab, 0xbefc, 0xe19e, 0x0038, 0x5f5a},
   {0x4a8f, 0x5c9d, 0x66ab, 0x70b9, 0x12c7, 0x04d5, 0x3ee3, 0x28f1, 0xfa1f, 0xec0d,
    0xd63b, 0xc029, 0xa257, 0xb445, 0x8e73, 0x9861, 0x66d6, 0x70c4, 0x4af2, 0x5ce0,
    0x3e9e, 0x288c, 0x12ba, 0x04a8, 0xd646, 0xc054, 0xfa62, 0xec70, 0x8e0e, 0x981c,
    0xa22a, 0xb438, 0x123d, 0x042f, 0x3e19, 0x280b, 0x4a75, 0x5c67, 0x6651, 0x7043,
    0xa2ad, 0xb4bf, 0x8e89, 0x989b, 0xfae5, 0xecf7, 0xd6c1, 0xc0d3, 0x3e64, 0x2876,
    0x1240, 0x0452, 0x662c, 0x703e, 0x4a08, 0x5c1a, 0x8ef4, 0x98e6, 0xa2d0, 0xb4c2,
    0xd6bc, 0xc0ae, 0xfa98, 0xec8a, 0xfbeb, 0xedf9, 0xd7cf, 0xc1dd, 0xa3a3, 0xb5b1,
    0x8f87, 0x9995, 0x4b7b, 0x5d69, 0x675f, 0x714d, 0x1333, 0x0521, 0x3f17, 0x2905,
    0xd7b2, 0xc1a0, 0xfb96, 0xed84, 0x8ffa, 0x99e8, 0xa3de, 0xb5cc, 0x6722, 0x7130,
    0x4b06, 0x5d14, 0x3f6a, 0x2978, 0x134e, 0x055c, 0xa359, 0xb54b, 0x8f7d, 0x996f,
    0xfb11, 0xed03, 0xd735, 0xc127, 0x13c9, 0x05db, 0x3fed, 0x29ff, 0x4b81, 0x5d93,
    0x67a5, 0x71b7, 0x8f00, 0x9912, 0xa324, 0xb536, 0xd748, 0xc15a, 0xfb6c, 0xed7e,
    0x3f90, 0x2982, 0x13b4, 0x05a6, 0x67d8, 0x71ca, 0x4bfc, 0x5dee, 0x653e, 0x732c,
    0x491a, 0x5f08, 0x3d76, 0x2b64, 0x1152, 0x0740, 0xd5ae, 0xc3bc, 0xf98a, 0xef98,
    0x8de6, 0x9bf4, 0xa1c2, 0xb7d0, 0x4967, 0x5f75, 0x6543, 0x7351, 0x112f, 0x073d,
    0x3d0b, 0x2b19, 0xf9f7, 0xefe5, 0xd5d3, 0xc3c1, 0xa1bf, 0xb7ad, 0x8d9b, 0x9b89,
    0x3d8c, 0x2b9e, 0x11a8, 0x07ba, 0x65c4, 0x73d6, 0x49e0, 0x5ff2, 0x8d1c, 0x9b0e,
    0xa138, 0xb72a, 0xd554, 0xc346, 0xf970, 0xef62, 0x11d5, 0x07c7, 0x3df1, 0x2be3,
    0x499d, 0x5f8f, 0x65b9, 0x73ab, 0xa145, 0xb757, 0x8d61, 0x9b73, 0xf90d, 0xef1f,
    0xd529, 0xc33b, 0xd45a, 0xc248, 0xf87e, 0xee6c, 0x8c12, 0x9a00, 0xa036, 0xb624,
    0x64ca, 0x72d8, 0x48ee, 0x5efc, 0x3c82, 0x2a90, 0x10a6, 0x06b4, 0xf803, 0xee11,
    0xd427, 0xc235, 0xa04b, 0xb659, 0x8c6f, 0x9a7d, 0x4893, 0x5e81, 0x64b7, 0x72a5,
    0x10db, 0x06c9, 0x3cff, 0x2aed, 0x8ce8, 0x9afa, 0xa0cc, 0xb6de, 0xd4a0, 0xc2b2,
    0xf884, 0xee96, 0x3c78, 0x2a6a, 0x105c, 0x064e, 0x6430, 0x7222, 0x4814, 0x5e06,
    0xa0b1, 0xb6a3, 0x8c95, 0x9a87, 0xf8f9, 0xeeeb, 0xd4dd, 0xc2cf, 0x1021, 0x0633,
    0x3c05, 0x2a17, 0x4869, 0x5e7b, 0x644d, 0x725f}
};

unsigned crc16dnp_byte(unsigned crc, void const *mem, size_t len) {
    unsigned char const *data = mem;
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0xffff;
    crc &= 0xffff;
    while (len--)
        crc = (crc >> 8) ^
              table_byte[(crc ^ *data++) & 0xff];
    return crc;
}

// This code assumes that integers are stored little-endian.

unsigned crc16dnp_word(unsigned crc, void const *mem, size_t len) {
    unsigned char const *data = mem;
    if (data == NULL)
        return 0xffff;
    crc &= 0xffff;
    while (len && ((ptrdiff_t)data & 0x7)) {
        crc = (crc >> 8) ^
              table_byte[(crc ^ *data++) & 0xff];
        len--;
    }
    if (len >= 8) {
        do {
            uintmax_t word = crc ^ *(uintmax_t const *)data;
            crc = table_word[7][word & 0xff] ^
                  table_word[6][(word >> 8) & 0xff] ^
                  table_word[5][(word >> 16) & 0xff] ^
                  table_word[4][(word >> 24) & 0xff] ^
                  table_word[3][(word >> 32) & 0xff] ^
                  table_word[2][(word >> 40) & 0xff] ^
                  table_word[1][(word >> 48) & 0xff] ^
                  table_word[0][word >> 56];
            data += 8;
            len -= 8;
        } while (len >= 8);
    }
    while (len--)
        crc = (crc >> 8) ^
              table_byte[(crc ^ *data++) & 0xff];
    return crc;
}
```

Comment: My knowledge about CRC is very limited. I think that bitwise, bytewise and wordwise implementations return the same results. Right? If yes, how do, e.g., wordwise implementations handle data input, which is not a multiple of 4 bytes in a way that the result is still the same as of the bytewise implementation?

Comment: Yes, they return the same results. They differ only in speed. If a word-wise implementation has 1, 2, or 3 bytes left over at the end after processing four bytes at a time, then those bytes are processed using the byte-wise algorithm.

Answer (score 5):

There are several different varieties of CRC-16. See [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check).

Every of those will return different results from the same input.

So you must carefully select correct one for your program.

Comment: I'm using the same polynomial they're using (x^16 + x^15 + x^2 + 1)

Comment: Yep, but there are several intial values, xors, etc. See http://regregex.bbcmicro.net/crc-catalogue.htm

Answer (score 2):

```
for (pos = 0; pos < len; pos++) {
    crc ^= (uint16_t)buf[pos];     // XOR byte into least sig. byte of crc

    for (i = 8; i != 0; i--) {     // Loop over each bit
        if ((crc & 0x0001) != 0) { // If the LSB is set
            crc >>= 1;             // Shift right and XOR 0xA001
            crc ^= CRC16;
        } else {                   // Else LSB is not set
            crc >>= 1;             // Just shift right
        }
     }
}

return crc;
```

Comment: This works for CRC-16 for Modbus RTU, but it doesn't work for CRC-16-IBM (ANSI) with polynomial 0x8005. It's not enough to just put in 0x8005 for CRC16 here and it work (with initial CRC 0)

Answer (score 1):

I used the code example from:
http://www.sunshine2k.de/articles/coding/crc/understanding_crc.html#ch5

And also this utility to verify:
http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html

Answer (score -1):

To generate checksum for packet
for example this packet "78781101086655103641220800002122000fdcfd0d0a"
"dcfd" this is error checksum
this is generate by the "1101086655103641220800002122000f" these
people are so misunderstand that the generate the response checksum of "dcfd"
but the checksum is generated by using its own packet data..

7878 and odoa is fixed so..

```java
package org.traccar.helper;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.zip.CRC32;

public final class Checksum {

    private Checksum() {
    }

    public static class Algorithm {

        private final int poly;
        private final int init;
        private final boolean refIn;
        private final boolean refOut;
        private final int xorOut;
        private final int[] table;

        public Algorithm(int bits, int poly, int init, boolean refIn, boolean refOut, int xorOut) {
            this.poly = poly;
            this.init = init;
            this.refIn = refIn;
            this.refOut = refOut;
            this.xorOut = xorOut;
            this.table = bits == 8 ? initTable8() : initTable16();
        }

        private int[] initTable8() {
            int[] table = new int[256];
            int crc;
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                crc = i;
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                    boolean bit = (crc & 0x80) != 0;
                    crc <<= 1;
                    if (bit) {
                        crc ^= poly;
                    }
                }
                table[i] = crc & 0xFF;
            }
            return table;
        }

        private int[] initTable16() {
            int[] table = new int[256];
            int crc;
            for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                crc = i << 8;
                for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
                    boolean bit = (crc & 0x8000) != 0;
                    crc <<= 1;
                    if (bit) {
                        crc ^= poly;
                    }
                }
                table[i] = crc & 0xFFFF;
            }
            return table;
        }

    }

    private static int reverse(int value, int bits) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < bits; i++) {
            result = (result << 1) | (value & 1);
            value >>= 1;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static int crc8(Algorithm algorithm, ByteBuffer buf) {
        int crc = algorithm.init;
        while (buf.hasRemaining()) {
            int b = buf.get() & 0xFF;
            if (algorithm.refIn) {
                b = reverse(b, 8);
            }
            crc = algorithm.table[(crc & 0xFF) ^ b];
        }
        if (algorithm.refOut) {
            crc = reverse(crc, 8);
        }
        return (crc ^ algorithm.xorOut) & 0xFF;
    }

    public static int crc16(Algorithm algorithm, ByteBuffer buf) {
        int crc = algorithm.init;
        while (buf.hasRemaining()) {
            int b = buf.get() & 0xFF;
            if (algorithm.refIn) {
                b = reverse(b, 8);
            }
            crc = (crc << 8) ^ algorithm.table[((crc >> 8) & 0xFF) ^ b];
        }
        if (algorithm.refOut) {
            crc = reverse(crc, 16);
        }
        return (crc ^ algorithm.xorOut) & 0xFFFF;
    }

    public static final Algorithm CRC8_EGTS = new Algorithm(8, 0x31, 0xFF, false, false, 0x00);
    public static final Algorithm CRC8_ROHC = new Algorithm(8, 0x07, 0xFF, true, true, 0x00);

    public static final Algorithm CRC16_IBM = new Algorithm(16, 0x8005, 0x0000, true, true, 0x0000);
    public static final Algorithm CRC16_X25 = new Algorithm(16, 0x1021, 0xFFFF, true, true, 0xFFFF);
    public static final Algorithm CRC16_MODBUS = new Algorithm(16, 0x8005, 0xFFFF, true, true, 0x0000);
    public static final Algorithm CRC16_CCITT_FALSE = new Algorithm(16, 0x1021, 0xFFFF, false, false, 0x0000);
    public static final Algorithm CRC16_KERMIT = new Algorithm(16, 0x1021, 0x0000, true, true, 0x0000);
    public static final Algorithm CRC16_XMODEM = new Algorithm(16, 0x1021, 0x0000, false, false, 0x0000);

    public static int crc32(ByteBuffer buf) {
        CRC32 checksum = new CRC32();
        while (buf.hasRemaining()) {
            checksum.update(buf.get());
        }
        return (int) checksum.getValue();
    }

    public static int xor(ByteBuffer buf) {
        int checksum = 0;
        while (buf.hasRemaining()) {
            checksum ^= buf.get();
        }
        return checksum;
    }

    public static int xor(String string) {
        byte checksum = 0;
        for (byte b : string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)) {
            checksum ^= b;
        }
        return checksum;
    }

    public static String nmea(String string) {
        return String.format("*%02X", xor(string));
    }

    public static int sum(ByteBuffer buf) {
        byte checksum = 0;
        while (buf.hasRemaining()) {
            checksum += buf.get();
        }
        return checksum;
    }

    public static int modulo256(ByteBuffer buf) {
        int checksum = 0;
        while (buf.hasRemaining()) {
            checksum = (checksum + buf.get()) & 0xFF;
        }
        return checksum;
    }

    public static String sum(String msg) {
        byte checksum = 0;
        for (byte b : msg.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)) {
            checksum += b;
        }
        return String.format("%02X", checksum).toUpperCase();
    }

    public static long luhn(long imei) {
        long checksum = 0;
        long remain = imei;

        for (int i = 0; remain != 0; i++) {
            long digit = remain % 10;

            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                digit *= 2;
                if (digit >= 10) {
                    digit = 1 + (digit % 10);
                }
            }

            checksum += digit;
            remain /= 10;
        }

        return (10 - (checksum % 10)) % 10;
    }

    public static int ip(ByteBuffer data) {
        int sum = 0;
        while (data.remaining() > 0) {
            sum += data.get() & 0xff;
            if ((sum & 0x80000000) > 0) {
                sum = (sum & 0xffff) + (sum >> 16);
            }
        }
        while ((sum >> 16) > 0) {
            sum = (sum & 0xffff) + sum >> 16;
        }
        sum = (sum == 0xffff) ? sum & 0xffff : (~sum) & 0xffff;
        return sum;
    }

}
```

for check your code use this as a example "78781101086655103641220800002122000fdcfd0d0a"
pass it "1101086655103641220800002122000f"
and it  answer  is "dcfd"  meansyour code work fine

ignore 8a51 this is for just checking Don't worry
for help :royalsuthar96@gmail.com

import this checksum in checksumExample and boom

my Checksum is in org.traccar.helper folder  ..

```
`enter code here`package org.traccar.helper;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class ChecksumExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Convert the hexadecimal string to a byte array
        String hexData = "1101086655103641220800002122000f";
        byte[] dataBytes = hexStringToByteArray(hexData);

        // Create a ByteBuffer from the byte array
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(dataBytes);

        // Use the CRC-16 algorithm
        int crcValue = Checksum.crc16(Checksum.CRC16_X25, buf);

        // Convert the expected checksum "8a51" to an integer
        int expectedChecksum = Integer.parseInt("8a51", 16);

        // Verify the checksum
        boolean checksumMatch = crcValue == expectedChecksum;

        System.out.println("Generated CRC-16: " + Integer.toHexString(crcValue));
        System.out.println("Expected CRC-16: " + Integer.toHexString(expectedChecksum));
        System.out.println("Checksum Match: " + checksumMatch);
    }

    // Helper method to convert a hexadecimal string to a byte array
    private static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String hex) {
        int len = hex.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(hex.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(hex.charAt(i + 1), 16));
        }
        return data;
    }
}


``
```