# Library for CRC16 checksum in Elixir

Tags: elixir, crc, crc16

I need to calculate CRC 16 of a string in elixir. Is there an existing library for the purpose?

Comment: There are some Erlang implementations: [https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=crc16++language%3AErlang&type=Code&ref=searchresults](https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=crc16++language%3AErlang&type=Code&ref=searchresults)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also needed a CRC library in elixir, I just published a package for this:

https://hex.pm/packages/crc
https://github.com/TattdCodeMonkey/crc

Comment: Actually I need a library for CRC-16 (plain, not CCITT). http://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html , on  this link a hex string - "test" (without quotes) gives 0xC481 as answer for CRC-16, which is correct. Can you suggest any library for plain CRC-16 ?

Comment: I already tried yours, but CCITT is not what I require right not.

Comment: Not off hand. If you can find a C library that does "plain" I could work on adding a function for it. In looking for libraries as examples I had a hard time finding "crc-16" everything was a specific flavor (ccitt, modbus, x_modem etc)

Comment: Hi, I was able to find a CRC-16 implementation in C (exactly what I want) on this StackOverflow Question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564491/function-to-calculate-a-crc16-checksum . The accepted answer seems to be exactly what I want (judging from the result it is giving). If you could implement that in your library, that would be great!

Comment: I will look into that this weekend, and comment back here.

Comment: Updated https://hex.pm/packages/crc with a crc16 implementation based on the provided code. Test is passing according to crc given by crc online calculator.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Bdw, will it work for hex inputs as well?

Comment: It takes a binary. but you can easily turn a hex number into a binary

`number = 0x1234`
`data = <<number::size(16)>>`