# Convert QByteArray to uint8_t*(uint8_t array)

Tags: c++, qt

How can I convert `QByteArray` coming from `QFile::readAll()` into a `uint8_t` array(`uint8_t*`)?

I tried `static_cast<>()` but didn't seemed to work for whole array.

examples of what I've done with `static_cast`:

```cpp
uint8_t* x = new uint8_t;
x[0] = static_cast<uint8_t>(testWav.readAll()[0]);
```

```cpp
uint8_t* x = new uint8_t;
*x = static_cast<uint8_t>(*testWav.readAll());
```

etc. didn't work

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't do what you want.

```
 uint8_t* x = new uint8_t;
 x[0] = static_cast<uint8_t>(testWav.readAll()[0]);
```

This way you copy only [0] element of array. The rest of allocated memory stay uninitialized

This cannot work at all:

```
uint8_t* x = new uint8_t;
*x = static_cast<uint8_t>(*testWav.readAll());
```

`QByteArray` is a class-type of dynamic container, so you can't use `static_cast` to access its data as an array, it's a principally different, incompatible data structure. And you're still assigning only the first element: `*x` is an equivalent of `x[0]`.

`QByteArray` has method `QByteArray::data()` which returns a pointer to `char*`:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qbytearray.html#data

The pointer returned by `data()` isn't owning one and points to memory allocated by class, so data contained in `QByteArray` which returned by `readAll()` will cease to exist at end of statement containing it, unless it's assigned to a more persistent storage:

```
QByteArray fileContent = file.readAll();
char *buffer = fileContent.data();
```

Result of `fileContent.size()` would give the actual size of buffer. Note that in some cases it's more convenient to work with QByteArray instead of a raw pointer. You need conversion ONLY if you have to use some API taking raw pointer or face some performance issues.

Comment: I did `char* data = testFile.readAll().data();`, but then how can I turn char array to uint8_t array?

Comment: note that OP makes the static cast on one element of the array, not the whole `QByteArray`

Comment: @kaankaya you can't do that in one line, that pointer will point at freed memory, because QByteArray will cease to exist as a temporary.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number that's another problem, that's likely isn't the intended result, because whole content of file will be lost after that supposed action.

Comment: @kaankaya why do you think you need to convert the `QByteArray` ? What do you need the `uint8_t` array for, and why can you not use the `QByteArray` for that ? It looks like there is a misunderstanding somewhere and we are helping at the wrong end

Comment: I do a crc16 calculation and it needs bytes-uint8_t*


it doesn't work correctly when I do it with const char* or char*

Comment: @kaankaya the horrible implementation of crc16 aside  that might be the case when use of raw pointer to buffer is OK.  `uint8_t` and `unsigned char` is  usually same type unless you have rather weird platform where char isn't a 8-bit byte, i.e. it's not a standard compiler.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I normally calculated crc16 on a hex string, turned it to uint8_t and the calculation is correct. Now I just want to do it for a file's data. I work on msvc qt

Comment: @kaankaya your implementation was correct in C but is not type-correct in C++ until ISO C++20 .  Mostly because of implicit upgrade of  bitwise  operation result to a signed int.  You can peek here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564491/function-to-calculate-a-crc16-checksum

Comment: also, MSVC is a "weird"  not-quite-standard compiler. It's likely was raising run-time check exceptions on assignments there unless you do proper  multiplication with a mask. WHich doesn't work with signed.

Answer (score 0):

I think first you need to know that a pointer is not an array. And that you cannot assing a c-array as a whole.

Then you should reconsider if you actually need to convert anything. `QByteArray` grants you access to the underlying array via its `data` member. (I find it a bit unfortunate that `QByteArray` is based on `char` rather than `unsigned char`, so you'd want to check whether `char` is signed or not).

Eventually, if you still want, you can write a loop to copy elements from the `QByteArray` to another array.