# Custom Checksum Algorithm

Tags: c, assembly, checksum

Recently ported some old MASM checksum code into C.

The MASM code was used to compute a checksum on a buffer or file.

I'm curious about what algorithm it resembles?

Here's the correct equivalent logic in C: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Y4MKzn1f3)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t computeChecksum(uint8_t *data, size_t dataLength) {
    uint32_t checksum = 0;
    int rotateBits = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < dataLength; i += 4) {
        // Process data in 32-bit chunks.
        uint32_t chunk = *(uint32_t*)(data + i);
        // Perform the ROL operation.
        chunk = (chunk << rotateBits) | (chunk >> (32 - rotateBits));
        // XORs the rotated chunk with a running checksum.
        checksum ^= chunk;
        // The number of bit positions the data is rotated increases by 1
        // for each subsequent chunk and wraps around after 32.
        rotateBits = (rotateBits + 1) % 32;
    }

    return checksum;
}

int main() {
    uint8_t data[32] = {
        0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08,
        0x09, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F, 0x10,
        0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18,
        0x19, 0x1A, 0x1B, 0x1C, 0x1D, 0x1E, 0x1F, 0x20
    };

    uint32_t checksum = computeChecksum(data, sizeof(data));
    printf("Checksum: 0x%08X\n", checksum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Validity" based on what?

Comment: It appears to be a type of CRC – [Cyclic redundancy check](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check).

Comment: Have you tested it?  Does it do what you need it to do? As provided so far, your post is not really on topic here.  Maybe [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @ryyker: How do you figure it is not on topic? Stack Overflow is for general questions about programming, not just questions about how to write code. Questions about what code does are on topic.

Comment: This function can read memory beyond what was supplied if `dataLength` is not divisible by 4

Comment: @EricPostpischil - Can you think of any substantive answers to this question that will be something other than opinion?  'Is it valid' is too vague. And 'What does it resemble' can be answered by additional research.

Comment: @ryyker: Somebody could identify the specific algorithm, and there could be information about theory of operation, what errors it detects, what errors it could miss, and so on.

Comment: I did research to find if it resembles any standard algorithm, but I couldn't find anything. I've removed the word 'validity' as it was meant to ask if the custom algorithm is valid (not the C implementation code) or is the logic flawed and should be replaced with something more modern like a SHA or CRC32?

Comment: @vengy - The code you've posted is an implementation of a CRC algorithm.  It is useful in some applications.  Its validity though depends its intended application.  CRCs are fine for providing a certain level of confidence for some tasks, but because of the redundant/cyclic nature, if seeing repeating values of its CRC value for very large files is not acceptable, then it would not be valid for use in that specific application.

Comment: @ryyker As soon as I started porting that custom CRC algorithm, the mantra "don't roll your own" came to mind and I was curious if this was the case where a programmer implemented their own CRC flavor, thinking it was valid, but in reality, it wasn't. Anyhow, thanks for your time.

Comment: @vengy `(uint32_t*)(data + i)` is a problem due to alignment requirements.  I suspect `*(uint32_t*)(data + i)` risks aliasing issues too.  Both risk undefined behavior (UB).  `printf("Checksum: 0x%08X\n", checksum);` is UB when `unsigned` is not 32-bit.  Old code deserves update.

Comment: Algorithm weakness:  If data is all zeros, CRC is 0.  Typically the cases of all data bits zeros (or all ones) should generate a non-zero (non-all-ones) check code to detect catastrophic failure.  Given that it does not handle that trivial case casts suspicion on the overall robustness of the algorithm.  I'd caution against its use.

Comment: It resembles [CRC16 Checksum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564491/function-to-calculate-a-crc16-checksum) algorithm, imo.  This is only an opinion.

Comment: This does not look like a CRC to me. Instead, it seems to be a hash function.